# Multithread locking, fun times (practicing for midterm)

Tags: multithreading, locking, thread-safety, deadlock

Here is a question my study group is arguing about:

(g) Consider the following C# code:

```
public class Demo {
    private static readonly object a = new object();
    private static readonly object b = new object();

    public static void Main (string[] args) {
        Demo d = new Demo();
        Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(d.g);
        Task t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(d.h);
        t2.Wait();
        t1.Wait();
    }

    private void g() {
        lock (a) {
            lock (b) {
                Console.Write("G");
            }
        }
    }

    private void h() {
        lock (b) {
            lock (a) {
                Console.Write("H");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a multi-threaded program, so different executions may produce different results. Place a check-mark next to the complete output that the program might produce. (The last choice stands for no output.)
Output Answer

Output-------Possible?

```
GH  
HG  
G   
H   
(nothing)
```

What we think:

GH would be the output if t1 locked b before t2 locked b.

(nothing) would be the output if t1 locked a and then t2 locked b, because it would cause a deadlock

G would be the output if t1 locked b, and then while t1 still held the lock on b, t2 started, because the t2.wait would be waiting on t1 to finish.

Can’t think of how you could possibly get H or HG. However, one of us ran the code 200,000 times, and he got HG sometimes... I don't understand

I just don't feel certain about these answers though. What do you all think? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Edit: I meant sometimes we get HG. Never getting a single letter. (I edited my question as well, I just wanted to make sure people saw the edit by writing it in a comment as well). Also, thanks for your edit :)

Comment: You should edit your actual question rather than posting corrections in the comments. Also, never double space your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ever getting a single letter, that means one thread managed to obtain both locks. Which also means it will be able to release both locks, and the other thread will complete successfully - and print the other letter. With this reasoning, both `GH` and `HG` are possible outputs. Also, it is possible to hit the deadlock case, where thread 1 holds one lock, and thread 2 holds the other.

Comment: The one thing we are stuck on now is: 
How does t2.wait() and t1.wait() affect the situation? One member of our group is saying that t1 could lock a and b, and before it released b, the t2 thread started requesting a lock on b, which it wouldn't be able to get because t1 currently has that lock. Then, at that moment, before t1 has released b, and while t2 is still asking for a lock on b, the main thread continues to t2.wait(). Wouldn't that cause it to freeze? with the possibility of G printing out before the freeze? (sorry we're thickskulled!)

Comment: Oops! We figured it out! Sry!

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no guarantee that `g()` will be started before `h()`. As I understand the `StartNew()` doesn't actually start the task, but rather queues it up for the next available thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to get only G or only H is to have both function finish, but the program ends before the console flushes second letter.

Answer (score 0):

HG can happen because there is no guarantee of when a new thread starts to execute. After creating `Task t2` the operating system is free to run it first, then go back and run `t1`.